# Handlebars NodeJS - Checking variable value for select form field

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I have a web project in NodeJS where I receive a value via the POST method and I need to check the received value to choose the appropriate option in my form.

`<select name="status" class="form-select"> <option value="online">Online</option> <option value="offline">Offline</option> . . . </select>` 
I would like to check if the received value is "online" or "offline" and set the "selected" option in the .handlebars file

I'm using the site as a reference

https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#if

Comment: I think there is too much information missing from this post. You should share your server code to show how you are handling the POST body.